# TLSv1.2_2021 does not satisfy anymore enum value set when updating aws cloudfront distribution from AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

When we deploy our new cloudfront distribution in AWS from command line

`aws cloudfront update-distribution ...`

we now get the message that the TLS value (that we didn't change) is not in the enum

> An error occurred (MalformedXML) when calling the UpdateDistribution operation: 1 validation error detected: Value 'TLSv1.2_2021' at 'distributionConfig.viewerCertificate.minimumProtocolVersion' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy enum value set: [TLSv1.1_2016, SSLv3, TLSv1.2_2018, TLSv1.2_2019, TLSv1_2016, TLSv1]

In Cloudfront (web interface), the value "TLSv1.2_2021" is available and recommended. when we choose it and save, it works. It's only in CLI that it doesn't work.

thanks for your help

Comment: Have you checked if you are using the latest version of the CLI?

Answer (score 4):

We were using AWS-CLI 1.18 and we updated to AWS-CLI 2.5 and it works now.